# Adding UIStackView as a empty container in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, interface-builder, uistackview

My wish is to have a UIStackView added in the Storyboard with 0 height that I reference in the code to add subviews to programatically. However, Storyboard is complaining about that it doesn't have a height (I haven't set it, so it is correct that it warns me). I only want it to act as a dynamic container for other views. The UIStackView I am talking about is added as a subview inside another UIStackView.

[image]

It is the stackview below "Name Label" it is all about.

Answer (score 18):

1. Select your StackView which you want to set height 0
2. Select Size inspector
3. Select Intrinsic Size property of StackView
4. Change it to Placeholder from Default
5. Now change StackView Height as you wish!! even 0.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can hide you inner stack view using the boolean `.hidden` property. Create an outlet to the inner stack view, say `innerStackView`, and hide it at initialization using `innerStackView.hidden = true`, e.g.:

```
@IBOutlet weak var innerStackView: UIStackView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // ...

    innerStackView.hidden = true
}
```

This will hide the stack view even if it contains several other views; hence, it can act as your hidden dynamic container, and you needn't fiddle around with height properties. If you want to show the view again, simply bitswap the `.hidden` property to `innerStackView.hidden = false`.